# how to override svg elements like <text> in my external CSS

Tags: css, svg, text

my problem is to override svg elements like < text > in my external CSS.

for example, if I have `transform: rotate` in my < text > and I want to override this on a media querie `@media screen and (max-width: 28.125em)` in my CSS.

my html :

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">              
                <rect x="4" y="2" width="42" height="245" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"></rect>
                <text x="66" y="148" text-anchor="middle" font-size="38"
                transform="rotate(-90,40,150)">My heading</text>
</svg>
```

so now i have the media querie

```
@media screen and (max-width: 28.125em)
```

in my (extern CSS-stylechield)  and there I want the < text > `transform: rotate` is horizontal again, so that the text is displayed horizontally again.
how does that work, can you please help me

greeting the misanthrope

Comment: Instead of using transform as svg attribute, use it in css like this: `text{transform:rotate(-90deg);transform-origin: 40px 150px}` Now it can be overwritten with a media query

Comment: Yes, good, but it doesn`t work with Chrome and IE (Edge ans 10er) :o((

Comment: It works for me and but maybe I don't understand your question. Can you add an image with the desired result?

Comment: Well here: https://www.tassilosturm.de/test-umgebung/index_mitSVG_schriftzug_test.html  On the left side I have my header. 
I would like this if the screen width becomes narrower so @media screen and (max-width: 62.500){, then I would like my header with the heading at the top and horizontally arranged. That`s my plan.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom class to text element. Then you can do `transform: unset` for that class in media query to reset the transformation (in your own css file).

```
.transform-unset {
    transform: unset;
}
```

Edit: this will rotate the whole header, previous answer did not work for the svg element as it is not rotated, but rather made at the narrow size. Also you will have to change the positioning after the rotate.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 62.500em){
  header {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesent work for me. I`ve this in my html : <link href="/css/main-style_testA.css" rel="stylesheet"> but <text< doesen`t load this information. The text is already horizontal.  :o((

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Because when I copy the `<svg></svg>` you provided it is vertical and `transform: unset` turns it horizontal. What do you mean it doesn't load the information from css? Is it being overwritten by other styles or the file is not found? You can use browser's devtools to check if the style is being overridden and use `!important` if nothing else helps.

Comment: Yes, there see you can see an exercise area: https://www.tassilosturm.de/test-umgebung/index_mitSVG_schriftzug_test.html . If the screen window is narrower, the title (header)  should be arranged horizontally, at the top of the page. for example: @media screen and (max-width: 62.500){ ...

Comment: Added css to rotate whole header.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you may need is transforming the svg element like this:

```css
 svg { position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);  
  transition:all 1s;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 28.125em){
 svg { 
  transform: translate(0px, -100%) rotate(90deg);  
  height:100vw; 
}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">              
                <rect x="4" y="2" width="42" height="245" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"></rect>
                <text class="transform-unset"  x="66" y="148" text-anchor="middle" font-size="38" transform="rotate(-90,40,150)">My heading</text>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

After the OP's comments I've come up with this:

```css
@media all {
 /*Farben + Hintergrundbild*/
 html {
  background-color: hsla(211, 13%, 50%, 0.05);

 }

   
 footer {
  background-color: hsla(26, 100%, 50%, 0.65);  
  color: #000000;     
 }
 
 /*Schrift*/
 html {
   font-family: 'Variable-Bold' sans-serif;
   font-size: 120%;
   line-height: 100%;
   hyphens: auto;
 }

 
 svg { display:block;
        margin:auto;
    
      position: absolute;
     top: 0;left: 0;bottom:0;right:0;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     transform: rotate(0deg);  
     transition:all 1s;
 }

 
 /* Grundlayout */
 html, * {
   margin:0; 
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 *, ::before, ::after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
 html, body {
  height: 100vh;
 }
 
 body>main { 
     max-width: 68em;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
 main { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100vh;
        flex: 1 0 59em;
        min-width: 59em;
        margin-left: 4em; /* Platz links fuer den Header schaffen */
        border: 3px dotted red;
    }
 
 
 header { 
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        /* flex: 0 0 3rem; */
        width: 5rem;
        min-height: 5rem;
        height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center; 
        align-content: center;
        border: 14px dotted green;

        position: fixed; /* Header fixieren und Position festlegen */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }


 header h1 {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        height: 5rem;
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        outline: 0.5rem solid orange;
        white-space: nowrap;
    
        display: inline-block;
    
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    
        position:relative;
    }
 
    
    
    /*footer*/
    
    footer {
        margin-top: auto;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    }


/*media queries*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 93.5em){
  svg { 
      transform: rotate(90deg);  
      height:50vw; 
        
  }
   header {
   height: 5rem;
   width: 100vw;
  }
  header h1 {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
      
  }
  main {
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-top: 5rem;
  }
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 50 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">              
     <rect x="4" y="2" width="42" height="245" stroke-width="5" stroke="orange" fill="none"></rect>
     <text x="66" y="148" text-anchor="middle" font-size="38" transform="rotate(-90,40,150)">Tassilo Sturm</text>
    </svg>
  </h1>
</header>

<main>

  <footer>
    <p>Copyright © 2019 Tassilo Sturm. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
  </footer>
</main>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: quiet good, I like it.  I try to install this in my flexbox framework, because my heading should not take 100% of the width or height: See my website: https://www.tassilosturm.de/test-umgebung/index_mitSVG_schriftzug_test.html  So, I hope now that the edge also plays along and the 10er IE,  in code snippet supported with javascript it understandably works.

Comment: So, i put it together and that is my result: https://www.tassilosturm.de/test-umgebung/index_mitSVG_schriftzug_test__V2.html  Who can please help me with these problems.

Comment: I've seen your demo. Please explain what exactly would you like to happen that it doesn't happen in your demo

Comment: that my svg is always inside <header> (always centered)  ((<header> ==  that´s the green outlined line)) , even if the breakpoint is reached and the <header> gets horizontal and so also the svg (inside <header>) gets horizonta (too)l. if the header is vertical it should be fixed and centered in height. when the breakpoint is reached, the font should be centered in horizontal (inside <header>). the lettering, so my svg 12em high / or be wide (and always in the middle).   that`s my plan.

Comment: I'm not angry LOL. Please explain me what else do you need compared with my demo.

Comment: Please do not be angry, it's almost like that, but very good. THX  a) The extra twist when it is vertical or when it is horizontal bothers me.218/5000
so if a) the font <header> is horizontal it's not fidgeting and spinning, but static when the breakpoint is reached, the <header> is displayed statically horizontally, and not always wriggling like that b) the yellow outline is superfluous. c) if <header <is horizontal, the svg should also be based on <header>, so arrange it in the middle, everything within <header> not above it . that would be it

Comment: I don't understand everything you are saying but you may remove the `transition:all 1s;` from the css. This should remove the fidgeting and spinning. The yellow outline was there as a border. The border was bothering me so I've changed to an outline. You can remove it.

Comment: in the horizontal state the svg is not <header>, adjusted, the svg is bigger and shows over <header>

Comment: For this you will need to add a max-width for the svg (5rem?)

Comment: Okay, works, now the heading conten (the red lined) protrudes into the main, so main would have to go down a bit